# Autoplay functions in PC Browsers but not in iPad Safari - WordPress - mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

Using WordPress 3.3.1 for audia using following:
[mejsaudio src="http://xxxxxx.mp3" loop="true" autoplay="true"]
The autoplay works properly on PC in IE and Firefox but does not work on iPad 2 in Safari.  Please advise how to properly code or otherwise make adjustments.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, autoplay is disabled for mobile safari, which is what the iPhone and iPad use.

> In Safari on iPhone OS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, autobuffering and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() method is triggered by user action.